# Badge tracker stuck?

Tags: bug, badges

I still have some work to do before reaching the PostgreSQL gold badge, so I chose it as the one for tracking.  Unfortunately, it seems to be stuck.  See the screenshot below:

[image]

I am not posting about anything else than Postgres (except comments), don't get many upvotes on answers on other topics (or question in general), so I was expecting the counter advancing nearly linearly with my reputation changes.  But it does not happen:

[image]

Please note that between taking the two screenshots, two days passed - so it's not like not waiting enough for the updates to be triggered.

Meanwhile, in the [top users view of the postgresql tag](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql/topusers), I seem to have accumulated some 221 answers with a total score of 727.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I experienced the same issue while tracking my gold SQL Server tag.  I needed to reselect the badge from the tracker for it to actually update the graph.

This has been asked-and-answered at ["Next tag badge" panel score and answers counter discrepancy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267818/next-tag-badge-panel-score-and-answers-counter-discrepancy) - unfortunately, the answer is the workaround I talked about above.

I suppose since this was marked as a bug, it might get some attention in 6-8 weeks.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  On the other hand, that question is already nearly four months old - it's more than 6-8 weeks.  Should I be pessimistic? :)

Comment: Yes.  Be [very pessimistic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190736/what-is-the-origin-of-6-to-8-weeks-and-is-it-really-the-crazy-frog).